# en ion-input text como hacer dinámico el maxlength

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Tengo un `Select` del **Tipo de documento** donde están las opciones *Cédula | RUC*; necesito que el `maxlength` varié según el tipo seleccionado. Cuando sea cédula maxlength=10 y para RUC maxlength=13

Intente lo siguiente pero no me funciona:

create.html

```
<ion-item >
  <ion-label>Tipo de documento</ion-label>
  <ion-select formControlName="codSecTrans" (ionChange)="setCustomerFinal($event)">
      <ion-option value="04">RUC</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="05">Cedula</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item> 
  <ion-label inline >RUC{{maxVal}}</ion-label>  <!-- coloque el maxVal acá y se modifica en el evento change -->
  <ion-input type="text" formControlName="ruc" maxlength="{{maxVal}}"></ion-input>
  <!-- pero en el ion-input se mantiene maxlength=13 -->
</ion-item>
```

create.js

```
export class ClientCreatePage {
  maxVal: any = 13;

  setCustomerFinal(event){
      switch (event) {
      case "04": //RUC
        this.maxVal = 13;
        break;

      case "05": //Cedula
        this.maxVal = 10;
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifica tu método de esta manera:

```
setCustomerFinal(event){
  switch (event.detail.value) {
  case "04": //RUC
    this.maxVal = 13;
    break;

  case "05": //Cedula
    this.maxVal = 10;
    break;
  }
```

}

El parámetro event trae varios campos que definen todo el evento, no solo el valor del mismo, por eso es necesario acceder al valor mediante event.detail.value

Comment: Gracias, esto ayuda a mejorar el código pero no soluciona el problema..

Answer (score 0):

En este caso creo que debes poner:

```
<ion-input type="text" formControlName="ruc" [maxlength]="maxVal"></ion-input>
```

Comment: Gracias pero tampoco funciona, el `maxlength` se mantiene de 13 caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```js
  setCustomerFinal(){
      switch (this.maxVal) {
      case "04": //RUC
        this.maxVal = 13;
        break;

      case "05": //Cedula
        this.maxVal = 10;
        break;
      }
   }
```

```html
<ion-item >
  <ion-label>Tipo de documento</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="maxVal" (ionChange)="setCustomerFinal()">
    <ion-select-option value="04">RUC</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="05">Cedula</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

La solución que te propone Marvin debería funcionar.

Comment: Lo que no funciona es esta parte `<ion-input type="text" formControlName="ruc" maxlength="{{maxVal}}"></ion-input>` no se modifica esta parte `maxlength="{{maxVal}}"`

Comment: No, eso está funcionando perfectamente, Cesar. La solución que te ha propuesto Marvín es la más correcta.

switch (event.detail.value) en vez de switch (event), pruébalo y nos cuentas.